# Cypher: Find shortest path between two nodes identified by their IDs

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Is this cypher-query correct? I am trying to find the shortest path between two nodes based on the node-IDs:

```
MATCH (martin:RoadNode {id:16814}),(oliver:RoadNode {id:16820}),
p = shortestPath((martin)-[*..15]-(oliver))
RETURN p
```

It does execute without error, but it returns 0 rows, although I expect it to find a path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found it! In order to find the shortest path between to nodes based on their IDs, this cypher-query does the trick:

```
MATCH (martin:RoadNode),(oliver:RoadNode),
p = shortestPath((martin)-[*..15]-(oliver)) 
WHERE id(martin) = 16814 AND id(oliver) = 16820
RETURN p
```

Comment: Note that the 15 here is optional, default depth limit for shortestPath is 15

Comment: What should be the query incase of weighted graph(Assume a property of relationship is used for calculating distance between two nodes)?